# Copying data and updating ParentId (Attachment)

Tags: apex, soql, dml

I have Custom object and Attachment and I need a way to copy all the data and update the `Attachment.ParentId = Custom_object__c.Id` with newly created record in the Custom_object__c.... I think I'm almost there but stuck in how to set the ParentId.

Here is what I got so far:

```
Set<Id> oldSetIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> newSetIds = new Set<Id>();

List<Custom_object__c> oldList = /*SELECT id,name.... from Custom_object__c where Id = 'xxxxx' */

List<Custom_object__c> newList = new List<Custom_object__c>();

for(Custom_object__c c : oldList)
{
   Custom_object__c cloneC = c.clone(false,false,false,false);  
   oldSetIds.add(c.Id);
   cloneC.Id = null
   newList.add(cloneC);   
}
insert newList;
```

//get the latest parentId that as been newly inserted

```
for(Custom_object__c c1 : newList)
{
   newSetIds.add(c1.Id);
}
```

Attachment:

```
List<Attachment> attachmentList = [Select Id, Name, ContentType, 
      ParentId, Description, Body 
     from Attachment Where Parent.Type = 'Custom_object__c' 
     and ParentID IN: oldSetIds];

List<Attachment> newAttachments = new List<Attachment>();

for(Attachment att : attachmentList)
{
    Attachment newAttach = new Attachment();
    newAttach.Body = att.Body;
    newAttach.ContentType = att.ContentType;
    newAttach.Description = att.Description;
    newAttach.Name = att.Name;
    newAttach.ParentId = ???//insert the new ParentId from newSetIds,            
    //I can not use att.ParentId if I used then it means that 
    //I'm still pointing to the old Parent record.
    newAttachments.add(newAttach); 
} 

insert newAttachments;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Map` for both the `List` and the `Set`:

```
Map<Id,Custom_object__c> newObjectByOldIds = new Map<Id,Custom_object__c>();

for(Custom_object__c c : oldList) {
   Custom_object__c cloneC = c.clone(false,true,false,false);  
   newObjectByOldIds.put(c.Id, cloneC);
}
insert newObjectByOldIds.values();

Attachment[] attachmentList = [
    SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, 
           ParentId, Description, Body 
    FROM Attachment 
    WHERE Parent.Type = 'Custom_object__c' 
        AND ParentId IN: newObjectByOldIds.keySet()];

Attachment[] newAttachments = new Attachment[]{};

for(Attachment att : attachmentList){
    Attachment newAttach = new Attachment();
    ...
    //this is not safe - you need null checks, but you get the idea.
    //When you insert the list of onewObjectByOldIds.values, they get ids.
    newAttach.ParentId = newObjectByOldIds.get(att.ParentId).Id;           
    newAttachments.add(newAttach); 
}
```

Note, I've set the second clone parameter to true - this means it's a proper deep clone. Also, setting the first parameter to false means that you don't need to nullify the id.